# why are parent.getpid() and child.getppid() different

Tags: process, fork, pid

I am trying to understand the consept of process. So I wrote a program like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main() {
  pid_t  pid;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
    printf("This is the child process. My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
  else
    printf("This is the parent process. My pid is %d and my child's id is %d.\n", getpid(), pid);
}
```

I expected this program would print something like

```
This is the parent process. My pid is 2283 and my child's id is 2284.
This is the child process. My pid is 2284 and my parent's id is 2283.
```

But instead, it prints this

```
This is the parent process. My pid is 2283 and my child's id is 2284.
This is the child process. My pid is 2284 and my parent's id is 1086.
```

At the end of the second line, the parent pid of the child is different form the parent process's pid.
Why is this happening? Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested your sample and cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. On my system it works as you (and me) expect. I have Windows 10, cygwin, gcc 5.4.0. Strange...

Comment: I tested it also on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55a061ea3b2c1c6a). The same result - it works as expected.

Comment: I run this program on Oracle VM Ubuntu. Does it happen because of it?

Comment: I think it happens because the parent process terminates before the child process calls getppid().

Comment: Hmm. Sounds reasonable. (Although, I'm not sure. I believe an exiting parent should kill its children processes.) To test his, you could add a `wait()` to the parent process branch. Additionally, the parent process can also output its ppid to confirm your guess.

Comment: This is because the parent process is terminating first, then the child process is being assigned as son of init process which probably its pid on your OS is `1086`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint of Tony Tannous was correct: The child may live longer than the parent. When the parent is exiting its child process is "hung up" i.e. it becomes child process of the init process.

I modified the sample code of OP to force the child process living longer then the parent process.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t  pid;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    sleep(1); /* 1 s */
    printf(
      "This is the child process."
      " My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
  } else {
    printf(
      "This is the parent process."
      " My pid is %d and my child's id is %d.\n", getpid(), pid);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with gcc on cygwin:

```
$ gcc -o test-pid-ppid test-pid-ppid.c

$ ./test-pid-ppid
This is the parent process. My pid is 10748 and my child's id is 10300.

$ This is the child process. My pid is 10300 and my parent's id is 1.
```

In my test this is obvious due to the specific PID 1 (the PID the init process usually gets). I'm a little bit surprised about  PID `1086` observed in the OP but:

1. There is no specification (I know) that init process must get PID 1 - its only usual.
2. The OP was run on a VM. There, may be, things are done slightly different than usual...

Concerning my belief that an exiting process would kill all of its children, I investigated further and found this: [Is there any UNIX variant on which a child process dies with its parent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158727/is-there-any-unix-variant-on-which-a-child-process-dies-with-its-parent). In short: my belief was wrong. Thank's for that question which forced me to enlightment.